# Gas will not flow into tank

Tags: fuel-system

I have a 2012 Jeep Wrangler. Recently, I attempted to pump gas in my nearly empty tank, and after 4-5 Seconds, the gas began to backflow onto the ground.
Each time I attempted to pump the gas, the pump would shut off.
I can only pump a few cents of gas before the pump shuts off and the gas flows out onto the ground.

Please tell me what the problem is?

Comment: is the check engine light on?

Comment: First thought is a blocked fill breather ...

Comment: Also, possible EVAP solenoid or charcoal canister.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem as well but it turned out that the vent hose for the tank was blocked.  It's pretty easy to tell if the filler tube or the vent hose is blocked: try filling the tank while holding down the white vent button right under the filler flap.  If the gas flows better, the vent hose is likely the problem.  If not, it's likely the filler tube.

Answer (score 3):

There is a filler tube running from the fill point to the gas tank. I would assume there's an obstruction (rust from the tube itself, something that fell in through the fill hole, etc.) in this tube. it is often possible to remove the filler tube without removing the gas tank, but you very well may have a better time with it by draining and dropping the tank.